# What is the json total records path for Qliksense REST connector?

Tags: json, qliksense

I have a json respone from Outreach API and for pagination in qliksense REST connector i need to pass through the total records path. What is path for following json response?

[image]

Here's where i need to put this into.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi url for total pagination depends on API. Alternatively you can try to call API in chunks and check for more. Example from other API:

```
SUB getOnePage(vOffset)

  LIB CONNECT TO [outreach_api];

  RestConnectorMasterTable:
  SQL SELECT 
  (...)
  FROM JSON (wrap on) "root" PK "__KEY_root"
  WITH CONNECTION (Url "https://api.outreach.io/api/v2/prospects?page[limit]=100&page[offset]=$(vOffset)");

  LET vHasMore = Peek('has-more',-1); 
  /* you need to find parametr which detects more rows or alternatively
  count returned number of records is more than 0 */

  LET vNext = Peek('next',-1);

  DROP Table root;

  IF vHasMore = 'True' then

    CALL getOnePage($(vNext));

  EndIf

EndSub

CALL getOnePage(0)
```